# Cannot use Ng-bootstrap in Angular 9

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9

I started my first project in angular with ng-bootstrap and followed the installation procedure, but nevertheless It doesn't work.

The message is "Uncaught Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using `i18n`.

Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please add `import '@angular/localize';` to your polyfills.ts file."

Then I added in polyfill.ts the line

```
import '@angular/localize';
```

and now the message changed to

> ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '
>   @angular/localize' in 'D:\source\mh\Reclamos-v2\src'

What should I install? What is the name of localize library?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you still have a dependency on the i18n library in your package.json left over from a previous Angular version? If so, that probably needs to be removed.

Comment: Hey Gustavo, did you make it work on Angular 9? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
npm install @angular/localize --save
```

Comment: See also: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#i18n

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to both install the package and to import it in `polyfills.ts`. The easiest way to achieve this is running:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred for me even after removing the package. Removing the import statement from polyfill.ts resolves the issue for me.